# vmware | virtual machine vmdk hdd error

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

After power troubleshooting I get this message:

```
 Reason: 5 (Input/output error).
 Cannot open the disk '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/tory/tory-000002.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
```

How I can fix it? Creating new disk from old is failed (with vmkfstools), parentCID and CID value is correct.

What else can I do?

```
Input/output error (327689)
```

FYI: it happened because of a problem with electricity (Faulty UPS).

---

**Further Detail**

```
Jun 03 12:26:59.808: vmx| DISK: OPEN scsi0:0 '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk' persistent R[]
Jun 03 12:26:59.824: vmx| DISKLIB-VMFS  : "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002-delta.vmdk" : open successful (10) size = 26742988800, hd = 16581470. Type 8
Jun 03 12:26:59.824: vmx| DISKLIB-DSCPTR: Opened [0]: "ctory-000002-delta.vmdk" (0xa)
Jun 03 12:26:59.824: vmx| DISKLIB-LINK  : Opened '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk' (0xa): vmfsSparse, 104857600 sectors / 50 GB.
Jun 03 12:26:59.827: vmx| DISKLIB-VMFS  : "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-flat.vmdk" : open successful (14) size = 53687091200, hd = 4490092. Type 3
Jun 03 12:26:59.827: vmx| DISKLIB-DSCPTR: Opened [0]: "ctory-flat.vmdk" (0xe)
Jun 03 12:26:59.827: vmx| DISKLIB-LINK  : Opened '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory.vmdk' (0xe): vmfs, 104857600 sectors / 50 GB.
Jun 03 12:26:59.827: vmx| DISKLIB-CHAINESX : ChainESXOpenSubChain: numLinks = 2, numSubChains = 1
Jun 03 12:26:59.884: vmx| DISKLIB-CHAINESX : ChainESXOpenSubChainNode: can't create deltadisk node 746e6f09-ctory-000002-delta.vmdk failed with error Input/output error (0xbad000a, I/O error)
Jun 03 12:26:59.884: vmx| DISKLIB-CHAIN : "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk" : failed to open (Input/output error).
Jun 03 12:26:59.884: vmx| DISKLIB-VMFS  : "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002-delta.vmdk" : closed.
Jun 03 12:26:59.885: vmx| DISKLIB-VMFS  : "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-flat.vmdk" : closed.
Jun 03 12:26:59.885: vmx| DISKLIB-LIB   : Failed to open '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk' with flags 0xa Input/output error (327689).
Jun 03 12:26:59.885: vmx| DISK: Cannot open disk "/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk": Input/output error (327689).
Jun 03 12:26:59.885: vmx| Msg_Post: Error
Jun 03 12:26:59.886: vmx| [msg.disk.noBackEnd] Cannot open the disk '/vmfs/volumes/4d78ed66-47c6d550-de03-0017a4770002/ctory/ctory-000002.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
Jun 03 12:26:59.886: vmx| [msg.disk.configureDiskError] Reason: Input/output error.----------------------------------------
Jun 03 12:26:59.896: vmx| Module DiskEarly power on failed.
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on what events/actions led up to this?

Comment: Have you consolidated snapshots.

Comment: kinda get the feeling that its to late to consolidate.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mPAL64Kd more detail

Comment: The details Rex meant was what did you do between the time the VM worked fine the last time and now that you get this error?  Basically, what exactly did you (or someone else) do to screw this up?

Comment: @RealityExtractor Problem with electricity. Faulty UPS.

Comment: @tony roth Yes with the extra detail it is!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your crash has corrupted one of your virutal drive .vmdk files.

The ctory-flat.vmdk file is holding all of your data - this is the important one.
This file: ctory-000002-delta.vmdk is a snapshot, or a backup of the running vm at a point in time.

The other .vmdk files are 'descriptor' files, or the configuration files.

Your task is to rebuild this 'descriptor' file to match the drive metrics of the virtual drive.

This [VMWare knowlegebase article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1002511) explains how to do it.